# sizeof struct or variable in C and C++

Tags: c++, c

I can't understand why this code prints 1 in C, but other digit in C++?

```
#include <stdio.h>
static char T = 'a';
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct T { char X[2]; };
    printf("size of T is %zu\n", sizeof(T));
}
```

And why this code prints 1 in both C and C++?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    static char T = 'a';
    struct T { char X[2]; };
    printf("size of T is %zu\n", sizeof(T));
}
```

Can somebody explain me this a little bit, please?

Comment: you have both a variable *and* a struct decl with the same name. Change the static char T to something other than T.

Comment: @WhozCraig:- thats Nikita's way....always exceptional... :)

Comment: @perilbrain lol I've apparently not been around long enough to recognize the origin of the question. I gotta pay more attention.

Comment: @WhozCraig, 2nd question is very interesting and I never knew that [it really compiles](http://ideone.com/b6lby)

Comment: @iammilind Yeah, Zeta hit it outta the park. I didn't pick up on the local-def hiding the outter def. Nice eye on his/her part.

Answer (score 21):

Because in `C` the struct is called `struct T` and not only `T`. In C++ the local definition of `struct T` will hide the global variable `T`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
static char T = 'a'; // (1)
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // `struct T` shadows outer `T` in C++
    struct T { char X[2]; }; // (2)

    // C: sizeof char (1); C++: sizeof struct T (2)
    printf("size of T is %u\n", sizeof(T));

    // C/C++: sizeof struct T (2)
    printf("size of struct T is %u\n", sizeof(struct T));
}
```

On the other hand, when both declarations are in the same naming context, the ambiguity of the identifier `T` will result in the same results, since C++ expects you to specify that you really want to use the struct and not the `char T`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    static char T = 'a';
    struct T { char X[2]; };
    printf("size of T is %u\n", sizeof(T)); // sizeof (char)
    printf("size of struct T is %u\n", sizeof(struct T));// sizeof struct T
}
```

Which results in the same size for both C and C++.

#### How to avoid this mistakes

Usually compilers do know that the identifier is ambiguous, but the warning is often hidden. Use compiler flags to show warnings, in GCC `-Wall -Wextra` are the most useful for usual programming:

```
test.cc: In function »int main(int, char**)«:
test.cc:5:43: Warning: unknown converting symbol »z« in format [-Wformat]
test.cc:5:43: Warning: to many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
test.cc: global:
test.cc:3:5: Warning: unused parameter »argc« [-Wunused-parameter]
test.cc:3:5: Warning: unused parameter »argv« [-Wunused-parameter]
test.cc:2:13: Warning: »T« defined, but not used  [-Wunused-variable]
```

In this case one will see that the global `static char T` has been defined, but never used.

Comment: C has a separate name space used only for struct tag/union tag/enum. Is this true also for C++?

Comment: @Lundin: A separate name space? Usually, in C, the name of a `struct name` is `struct name`, while in C++ `struct name` can be used with `name`, as long as there isn't a local other structure/function/variable which shares the name. I wouldn't call it separate name space, but simply other naming/lookup convention.

Comment: @Zeta In C, labels, struct/union/enum tags, struct/union members and plain variables are all in different name spaces (C11 6.2.3). The C standard calls it name space, not to be confused with scope. That is why weird code like `struct x { int x; } y; int x; x: ` compiles just fine. I merely wondered if C++ had the same "tag" concept as C.

Comment: @Lundin: Err... I'm not a language lawyer, but I guess this is the right section in C++: *"Change: A C++typedef name must be different from any class type name declared in the same scope (except if the typedef is a synonym of the class name with the same name). In C, a typedef name and a struct tag name declared in the same scope can have the same name (because they have different name spaces)"*. Btw: only labels seem to have their own name space (see [stmt.label]).

Answer (score 1):

In C, when a structure is declared, it is of type `struct <name of struct>` and not just the name of the struct. That is the reason. To avoid confusion, people use `typedef` to simplify the declarations in C

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, in the first snippet the local `struct T` will hide the static var in `C++`. However, to fully understand what's going on, you also have to talk about name disambiguation. In the second code snippet, `struct T` isn't hiding `T` - they're in the same scope.