# the third word in definition of an class in C++

Tags: c++, class

So recently I have recovered a source file of an C++, and since I am a beginner, I need some help:

```
//______________________________________________________________________

class ORBITDYN_API CMsise00
{
public:
    struct nrlmsise_input input;
    struct nrlmsise_flags flags;
    struct nrlmsise_output output;

public:
    CMsise00(void);
    ~CMsise00(void);

    //¼ÆËã´óÆøÃÜ¶È
    double Density(const CDateTime& t,const Vector& ECFr);
};

ORBITDYN_VAR CMsise00 Msise;

//___________________________________________________________________________
```

1. What is the meaning of `CMsise00` the third word in the class declaration?
2. The same question for structures declaration `input`, `flags` , `output`
3. What is the meaning of the last sentence  `(ORBITDYN_VAR CMsise00 Msise;)` it's a a call of another function or what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ORBITDYN_API` is most likely a macro that expands either to none or some compiler specific attribute, probably for dynamic linking (`__declspec(dllexport)` maybe?)

So your code should be read as:

```
class CMsise00
{
...
};
```

Now it is obvious that `CMsise00` is the name of the class.

And ditto for `ORBITDYN_VAR`.

These kind of macros are idiomatic when writing DLLs in Windows. The issue is that the functions, classes or variables exported should be declared as `__declspec(dllexport)` when compiling the DLL, but as `__declspec(dllimport)` when linking to it. A bit of preprocessor magic allows you to use the same header file for both cases.

Ah! I almost forgot the struct thing:

```
struct nrlmsise_input input;
```

That is just a variable named `input` of type `struct nrlmsise`. You could just write:

```
nrlmsise_input input;
```

and it would be the same. The former one is accepted in C++ for compatibility with C. In C you always use the struct names with the keyword `struct` before it.

Comment: I knew it was the preprocessor! Damn you, preprocessor!

Comment: @BlueIce: Yeah, the all uppercase and the `DYN` part are the key.

Comment: @rodrigo: Just an additional note on the `struct`: Actually, there can be a global identifier called `nrlmsise_input`. In this case, you need to use `struct` again, e.g. `struct bad{}; int bad(){return 1;} int main(){ struct bad b; return bad();}` See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833014/sizeof-struct-or-variable-in-c-and-c/12833053#12833053